# How to prevent default sorting in key value array Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I have this array:

```js
recentPageArray = {
  "e49f8a67-3075-433a-bacd-30379008fdb2": {
    "id": "e49f8a67-3075-433a-bacd-30379008fdb2",
    "name": "afolder",
    "type": "indexfolder"
  },
  "3a1ca419-5467-4662-9f7a-f3e9246a1d49": {
    "id": "3a1ca419-5467-4662-9f7a-f3e9246a1d49",
    "name": "folder1",
    "type": "indexfolder"
  },
  "832f9d4e-297e-40e9-9189-75ce3b86341a": {
    "id": "832f9d4e-297e-40e9-9189-75ce3b86341a",
    "name": "afolder",
    "type": "documentfolder"
  },
  "86fee1ce-21cd-4948-bf9d-a6c81b897a0e": {
    "id": "86fee1ce-21cd-4948-bf9d-a6c81b897a0e",
    "name": "afolder",
    "type": "documentfolder"
  }
}
```

Whenever I push new array in the this array. Key sort automatically. I dont want to sort array in the key base. I need new pushed key item in top of the array.

Comment: What key sorts? You mean when you use some rendering it sorts it?

Comment: Firstly, that's an object, not an array. Secondly, and more importantly, you cannot sort an object. Therefore what you're trying to do is impossible with the data structure you have

Comment: You don't have an array but an object. objects are typically unsorted, or sorted alphabetically. There's nothing you can do about it, but changing your object to actually be an array.

Comment: yes its object But it goes sort automatically when I add new record. Key sort menas: object={ key1{ " ", " ", ""} ,key2{ " ", " ", ""}, key3{ " ", " ", ""}. I have unique id in the key.

Comment: You cannot sort an object. The order the properties are shown in is completely arbitrary. If you need to guarantee an order you need to amend the logic to work with an array of objects.

Comment: I was not able to create this key value pair by 2d array in javascript. so thats why I have used object.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to mantain 2 references:
1 Array (list)
1 Object (key, value)

The Object (key->val) cannot mantain the elements' insert order (and if an utopic new browser implementation want to order in descending order(for any cause) your code will be sensible to it).

So, while populating the object,also push the element key in the Array.
When you want to iterate use the Array to iterate in order (and it is also faster)

```
myObject = {};
myArray = [];
/** POPULATING **/
for (var x in myData){
   myObject[myData[x].key] = myData[x].value;
   myArray.push(myData[x].key);

}
/** ITERATING **/
for (var y =0; y < myArray.length; y++){
   var readingKey = myArray[y];
   var storedData = myObject[readingKey];
   //your code here
}
```

Regards